# (Java Code) Return maximum occurring character in an input string

Tags: java, string

Can anyone please explain the process of this for loop which comes first in the code. If you print these two lines in the console, you get output [0 0 0 1 2]. I don't know "how it works behind the scene to increment the character count every time".

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
 count[str.charAt(i)]++; 

//Code
     public class GFG  
        { 
            static final int ASCII_SIZE = 256; 
            static char getMaxOccuringChar(String str) 
            { 
                // Create array to keep the count of individual 
                // characters and initialize the array as 0 
                int count[] = new int[ASCII_SIZE]; 

                // Construct character count array from the input 
                // string. 
                int len = str.length(); 
                for (int i=0; i<len; i++)   //bit confused lines
                    count[str.charAt(i)]++; 

                int max = -1;  // Initialize max count 
                char result = ' ';   // Initialize result 

                // Traversing through the string and maintaining 
                // the count of each character 
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
                    if (max < count[str.charAt(i)]) { 
                        max = count[str.charAt(i)]; 
                        result = str.charAt(i); 
                    } 
                } 

                return result; 
            } 

            // Driver Method 
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            { 
                String str = "abcaa"; 
                System.out.println("Max occurring character is " + 
                                    getMaxOccuringChar(str)); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: The code is well documented. Which line are you not able to understand?

Comment: If you're not able to understand the code, please use debug mode. Using debug mode you are able to follow execution of each line of this code, and see the declared variables and their values.

Comment: Your `count` array is of size 256 which is also the number of ASCII characters. Each ASCII `char` can be cast to and `int` with values falling between 0 and 255. As you're iterating over each of the `chars` in your `String`, each `char` is being implicitly cast to an `int` and then is being used as the index to access and increment the value in the `count` array.

Comment: @TrogDor There are only 128 ASCII characters, not 256. Character values of 128 and above are Unicode code point values, not ASCII character values.

Comment: @Andreas - not going to claim this is my area of expertise. But from what I understand, 128-255 in Unicode are called the "Latin-1 Supplement" block, and also sometimes referred to as "Extended ASCII Codes" specified by "ISO/IEC 8859".

Comment: @TrogDor Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII): *Using the term "extended ASCII" on its own is sometimes criticized,[1][2][3] because it can be mistakenly interpreted to mean that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, **neither of which is the case**. There are **many extended ASCII encodings** (more than 220 DOS and Windows codepages).* --- Hence the term "Extended ASCII" is misleading and doesn't define anything by itself, since it's a set of 220 different definitions.

Comment: @Andreas, I agree, referring to the values as Unicode is the more correct term. For the sake of explaining the code to the OP I felt it was fine to reference the vague concept of Extended ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop iterates over the string, the value of `str.charAt(i)` is the character of `str` at the index `i`.

Since every char corresponds to an int value (see more about that [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int)) `count[str.charAt(i)]++;` increases the value of the `count` array at the index of the given char's corresponding int (see the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see which one that is).

So after the for loop `count` contains the number of occurences of every ascii character in `str`.

Comment: Thank you. Your 3rd line explained it well and that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`str.charAt(i)` return char from `str` at the `i` position. Char can be used as index in array for example `myarray['c']` because `'c'` can be represented as number (see ASCII table).

So basically
`for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
  count[str.charAt(i)]++;`

is counting how many times the same letter appears in string.

so for input string "aabc"
`count['a'] = 2`
`count['b'] = 1`
`count['c'] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Maximum occurring character in a single input string

```
public static char getMaxOccuringChar(String str) {
    char result = ' ';
    int len = str.length();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> StrArray = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    int val = 1;
    for(int i =0; i<len; i++) {
        char temp = str.charAt(i);
        if(!StrArray.containsKey(temp)) {
            StrArray.put(temp, val);
        }else {
            StrArray.put(temp, StrArray.get(temp)+1);
        }
    }
    int MaxVal = 0;
    for(char i : StrArray.keySet()) {
        if(StrArray.get(i) > MaxVal) {
            result = i;
            MaxVal = StrArray.get(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the question asked to explain the code, not give another one